# How can I identify an embedded Linux distribution?

Tags: linux, embedded, synology

I'm trying to identify an embedded Linux distribution. Here are the commands I have typed so far:

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux LIN-SRV-EMB01 3.10.105 #25556 SMP Sat Aug 28 02:14:22 CST 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux synology_bromolow_rs3412rpxs

$ lsb_release
-sh: lsb_release: command not found

$ ls /usr/lib/os-release
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/os-release: No such file or directory

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.105 (root@build1) (gcc version 4.9.3 20150311 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG 1.20.0) ) #25556 SMP Sat Aug 28 02:14:22 CST 2021

$ cat /proc/cmdline
root=/dev/md0 netif_seq=2130 ahci=0 SataPortMap=34443 DiskIdxMap=03060e0a00 SataLedSpecial=1 ihd_num=0 netif_num=4 syno_hw_version=RS3412rpxs  macs=001132109b1e,001132109b1f,001132109b20,001132109b21 sn=LDKKN90098

$ dmesg | grep "Linux version"
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.10.105 (root@build1) (gcc version 4.9.3 20150311 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG 1.20.0) ) #25556 SMP Sat Aug 28 02:14:22 CST 2021
[  342.396803] Loading modules backported from Linux version v3.18.1-0-g39ca484

$ python -m platform
Linux-3.10.105-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5

$ which python2 && python2 -c "import platform;print platform.linux_distribution()[0]"
/bin/python2

$ which python3 && python3 -c "import distro;print(distro.name())"

$ more /etc/issue /etc/*release /etc/*version /boot/config*
more: stat of /etc/issue failed: No such file or directory
more: stat of /etc/*release failed: No such file or directory
more: stat of /etc/*version failed: No such file or directory
more: stat of /boot/config* failed: No such file or directory

$ zcat /proc/config.gz /usr/src/linux/config.gz | more
gzip: /proc/config.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: /usr/src/linux/config.gz: No such file or directory

$ which dpkg apt apt-get rpm urpmi yum dnf zypper
/bin/dpkg

$ df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0        2.3G  1.1G  1.1G  50% /

$ sudo parted /dev/md0 print
Password:
Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md0: 2550MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  2550MB  2550MB  ext4

$ sudo mdadm -Q /dev/md0
/dev/md0: 2.37GiB raid1 10 devices, 0 spares. Use mdadm --detail for more detail.

$ which lsblk lscsci lshw lspci dmidecode
/bin/lspci
/sbin/dmidecode
```

EDIT0: Tried two more commands :

```bash
$ strings $(ps -p 1 -o cmd= | cut -d" " -f1) | egrep -i "ubuntu|debian|centos|redhat" -o | sort -u
-sh: strings: command not found
[remoteserver] $ ssh embedded-linux 'cat $(ps -p 1 -o cmd= | cut -d" " -f1)' | strings | egrep -i "ubuntu|debian|centos|redhat" -o | sort -u
ubuntu
```

EDIT1: Tried three more commands :

```bash
$ which initctl && initctl --version
/sbin/initctl
initctl (upstart 1.13.2)
Copyright (C) 2006-2014 Canonical Ltd., 2011 Scott James Remnant

This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ which systemctl && systemctl --version
$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name
To be filled by O.E.M.
$
```

EDIT2: Tried one more command (specific to Synology) :

```bash
$ grep productversion /etc/VERSION
productversion="6.2.4"
```

EDIT3: Just in case one wants to identify the hardware :

```bash
$ uname -u # Specific to Synology ?
synology_bromolow_rs3412rpxs

$ sudo dmidecode -t system | grep Product
        Product Name: To be filled by O.E.M.
$

$ cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_name
To be filled by O.E.M.
$
```

EDIT4 : On another Synology, I get :

```bash
$ uname -u
synology_broadwell_rs3618xs
```

I guess it's based on Ubuntu+upstart.

EDIT5 : Distrib can be identified using [this Observium script](https://github.com/observium/distroscript/blob/master/distro) or [this LibreNMS script](https://github.com/librenms/librenms-agent/blob/master/snmp/distro).

What other commands can I use to look a little deeper?

Comment: It seems to be a Synology device, but presumably you’re aware of that; the distribution would be [DiskStation Manager](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm). Are you only trying to determine the distribution, or do you have a further goal in mind?

Comment: @StephenKitt I need to be able to administer from the command line.

Comment: @SebMa, what exactly you want to administer? Do not forget this is appliance and some of your actions from command line can void warranty.

Comment: What makes you think that is possible? Most devices with an embedded Linux aren't meant to be administrated.

Comment: Found this : https://kb.synology.com/en-ph/search?query=CLI&sources%5B%5D=user_guide&sources%5B%5D=white_paper&sources%5B%5D=developer_guide provided by Synology

Comment: So? Synology has documented how to *use* their boxes with a CLI interface, that doesn't mean you're supposed to do anything else.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity I agree but if using the CLI voided the warranty, they would not have publicly posted this CLI documentation.

Comment: @SebMa probably depends what you do

Comment: There's still a difference between *using the CLI* and doing any kind of administration that requires the knowledge you seek.

Comment: You could also try `lsb_release --all` or `lsb-release --all`. On Ubuntu 20.04 this command reads information from `/usr/lib/os-release` and `/usr/share/distro-info/debian.csv`

Comment: @MarkWagner `-sh: lsb_release: command not found` and `ls: cannot access /usr/lib/os-release: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `uname -a` output identifies this as a Synology device. Such devices run [Synology DiskStation Manager](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm). This is Linux-based, but it is *not* managed like a typical Linux system running a “traditional” Linux distribution. It has its own package manager, `synopkg`, for which third-party packages are made available by [SynoCommunity](https://synocommunity.com/). The [DiskStation CLI guide](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Firmware/DSM/All/enu/Synology_DiskStation_Administration_CLI_Guide.pdf) describes a few administration tools available in DSM.

If you’re interested in automating administrative tasks on such devices, you might find [Synology’s Central Management System](https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/help/CMS/cms_desc?version=7) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Also my "two cents":

```
$ cat /etc/*release*
```

Sometimes there is no dashes in release-related file names.

This outputs to stdout contents of all files under `/etc` directory containing `release` word in file name.

Comment: `cat: /etc/*release*: No such file or directory`

Comment: Looks like this Linux distribution doesn't have release description files. That's strange. Well, at least, this is consistent with `$ more /etc/issue /etc/*release /etc/*version /boot/config*` output.